# python For-loop fails when I tried to write a function with it in

Tags: python, loops

As a Python learner (version 2.7, 32 bit), I wrote a function with the loop in a python file named year.py like the following. But the loop doesn't work in Python compiler.

```
def fun(a):
    a_year = a + 7
    b = [a_year, a_year + 9, a_year + 2*9, a_year + 3*9]
    for i in b:
        return "Your years are: %d" % i
```

If I run the function in Python compiler like this:

```
import year
year.fun(1980)
Your years are: 1987
```

My question is, How should I make it return as following?

```
import year
year.fun(1980)
Your years are: 1987
Your years are: 1996
Your years are: 2005
Your years are: 2014
```

Thank you.

Comment: We can't make heads or tails of "Loop doesn't work". Do you have errors?

Comment: It works well, I just checked here

Comment: Did you call the function?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that function.

Comment: Are you passing right value to `fun`. It should be `a = int(raw_input("What's your birth year?(Example: 1980)"))` then `fun(a)`. It should work there is no difference between function and your 1st code

Comment: have you executed the function call? Ex: `fun(1980)`

Comment: Also, why learn python 2.7? Use 3.6.

Comment: Thank you guys! @sriharsha_bhat

Comment: Yeah I just tested the code. It works fine. Are you sure you're calling the function?

Comment: I have edit the question with more details. @Aran-Fey

Comment: @Ken Y-N, thank you guy! I add some details.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, I think I make my question detailed.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the problem. The code works fine.

Comment: I call it. @Chris_Rands

Comment: Please give me some advice. I have more details there on edits. @jpp

Comment: Thank you @Aran-Fey, the problem comes when I use "return", not "print", in the codes. I edited the question just now.

Comment: Duplicate of [return statement in for loops](//stackoverflow.com/q/5864166)

Comment: Thank you Aran, I solved the problem with your advice. @Aran-Fey

Answer (score -1):

It didnt work because you didnt assign the value for a.Try this

```
def fun(a):
    a_year = a + 7
    b = [a_year, a_year + 9,( a_year + 2*9), a_year + 3*9]
    for i in b:
        y ="Your years are: %d" %i
        print y

fun(3)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried as you advised. But it still doesn't work. anyway, thank you @Bilal Ali Jafri